# RXJS - subscription trigger multiple times. Nested Subscription with multiple if else conditions

Tags: angular, if-statement, rxjs-observables, angular-observable

want to optimize the following code:
multiple subscription in multiple if else statements.

consider:-

```
getList(): void {
    this.subs.sink = this.subscription1.subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.method1();
      }
    });
  }

method1() {
//code
//code
if (condition){
//code
} else {
this.method2()
}

method2(){
 this.subs.sink = this.subscription2.subscribe(
      (response) => {
if(){
//code
} else {
this.method3();
}
}

method3(){
this.subs.sink = this.subcription3.subscribe(
      (response) => {
//code
}
}
```

this resulting in triggering multiple subscription.

Any help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to streamline the multiple subscriptions. It depends what exactly the `// code` represents. If most of the `// code` are same, then you could possibly use `filter` to apply the condition.

The following method assumes each `// code` block is unique. It used `switchMap` to map from one observable to another. If you do not wish to forward the observable to the subscription's `next` block, you could return RxJS `EMPTY` constant. It would essentially complete the observable.

```js
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

getList(): void {
  this.subs.sink = this.subscription1.pipe(
    switchMap((user: any) => {
      // code
      if (condition) {
        // code
        return EMPTY;
      }
      return this.subscription2;
    }),
    switchMap((response: any) => {
      if (condition) {
        // code
        return EMPTY;
      }
      return this.subscription3;
    })
  ).subscribe({
    next: (response: any) => {
      // response from `this.subscription3`
      // code
    },
    error: (error: any) => {
      // handle error
    }
  });
}
```